# When mutate_all and lapply disagree ... How to replace lapply with mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, tidyverse

I'm here again to ask for your help! 
I'm trying to figure out what's happening with mutate_all (or with me...).

Let's say I have this dataset:

```
ds <- structure(list(Q1 = structure(c(5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                      5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 
                                      5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
                                      5, 4), label = "1 Para mim é igual se os meus amigos são heterossexuais ou homossexuais.", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 3L, class = "labelled", labels = c(`discordo totalmente` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          discordo = 2, indiferente = 3, concordo = 4, `concordo totalmente` = 5
                                      )), Q2 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 
                                                           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
                                                           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), label = "A homossexualidade é uma perturbação psicológica/biológica.", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 5L, class = "labelled", labels = c(`discordo totalmente` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     discordo = 2, indiferente = 3, concordo = 4, `concordo totalmente` = 5
                                                           )), Q3 = structure(c(5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 
                                                                                5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4), label = "Acredito que os pais e as mães homossexuais são tão competentes como os pais e mães heterossexuais.", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 5L, class = "labelled", labels = c(`discordo totalmente` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  discordo = 2, indiferente = 3, concordo = 4, `concordo totalmente` = 5
                                                                                )), Q4 = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
                                                                                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3), label = "4 Todas as Lésbicas, Gays, Bissexuais, Transexuais, Transgêneros e Intersexuais (LGBTI) me deixam irritado.", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 4L, class = "labelled", labels = c(`discordo totalmente` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               discordo = 2, indiferente = 3, concordo = 4, `concordo totalmente` = 5
                                                                                                     )), Q5 = structure(c(1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                                          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
                                                                                                                          1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3), label = "A legalização do casamento entre pessoas do mesmo sexo é muito errada.", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 5L, class = "labelled", labels = c(`discordo totalmente` = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               discordo = 2, indiferente = 3, concordo = 4, `concordo totalmente` = 5
                                                                                                                          ))), row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                          ))
```

Then I need to transform all variables into *factors* to plot them. I really like the dplyr approach:

```
ds_mutate <- ds %>% mutate_all(., factor, levels=1:5)
likert(ds_mutate)
```

But this error is coming up:

```
Error in likert(ds_mutate) : 
  All items (columns) must have the same number of levels
```

[image: STR mutate all]

When I use lapply (Nobody will convince me 'apply'functions are intuitive...), it works pretty well:

```
> ds_apply <- lapply(ds, factor, levels=1:5) %>% as.data.frame()
> likert(ds_apply)
  Item         1         2         3         4         5
1   Q1  1.851852  1.851852  9.259259 14.814815 72.222222
2   Q2 77.777778  9.259259  5.555556  7.407407  0.000000
3   Q3  0.000000  3.703704  1.851852 14.814815 79.629630
4   Q4 79.629630 14.814815  3.703704  0.000000  1.851852
5   Q5 72.222222  7.407407 14.814815  3.703704  1.851852
```

But as you can see, the str is (for me) the same...
[image: STR APPLY]

i'm looking forward to hearing from you!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one difference:

```
class(ds_mutate)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(ds_apply)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

The issue then arises from the fact that, in the call of `likert`, we have

```
nlevels = length(levels(items[, 1]))
```

where, in the former case,

```
length(levels(ds_mutate[, 1]))
# [1] 0
```

since

```
ds_mutate[, 1]
# A tibble: 54 x 1
#    Q1   
#    <fct>
#  1 5    
#  2 4    
#  3 5    
#  4 5    
#  5 5    
#  6 5    
#  7 5    
#  8 5    
#  9 5    
# 10 5    
# … with 44 more rows
```

i.e., the result is a tibble. Also,

```
methods("levels")
# [1] levels.default
```

so that there is no `levels` method for tibbles. Notice also that

```
class(ds_mutate) <- c("data.frame", "tbl_df", "tbl")
ds_mutate[, 1]
#  [1] 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 3 5 5 5 5 5 1 4 5 5 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 2 5 5 4 5 5 3 5 5 4 3 3 5 5 5
# [45] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 4
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

in which case

```
likert(ds_mutate)
```

starts to work too. Without modifying classes you may also use

```
likert(data.frame(ds_mutate))
```

**Extra**: `lapply` in

```
lapply(ds, factor, levels = 1:5)
```

actually is really intuitive once we understand one thing: a data frame is a special case of a list where each list element is of the same length. Know the way `sapply` or `lapply` works is that it goes over each element of the first argument: once we see `ds` as a data frame whose elements (since it's a list) are columns, it becomes clear how it operates. For the same reason, since the results of `factor` in this case are of the same length, the list resulting from the call to `lapply` nicely can be converted to a data frame.

Comment: @Luis, fyi, I downvoted your question as you accepted an answer that contains just a solution (which is contained in my answer as well), but no explanation (maybe all functions don't accept tibbles?), and was posted more recently; I suspect that the main motivation for that was that the author  had just 1 rep, but accepting answers on SO typically is about their value and correctness, not something else (unless there is a tie).

Comment: Hey, I don't know what is happening here and I'm having a hard time to figure out this behavior. I accepted the first answer because I saw the first answer before. It was not a question of clarifying my question, what you did, but it was a question of timing. Thanks again for your answer, it was very informative and comprehensive...

Answer (score 2):

I never used likert package but it looks like it doesn't take an object of the class tibble. This works for me:

```
likert(as.data.frame(ds_mutate))
```